# Why does Gson treat JsonNull and null the same?

Tags: json, gson

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.add("test", JsonNull.INSTANCE);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(obj));
```

Here is the output:

```
{}
```

I was expecting

```
{"test":null}
```

I thought the whole point of JsonNull is to differentiate between null and json null value. I understand that you can do `new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls()`but I have some real null fields that I don't want to serialize.

Thanks,